# multiple bounds for scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: scipy

In scipy.optimize.minimize

```
w0 = np.ones(assets_num) / assets_num   #assets_num is an integer
bnds_1 = tuple((0.25, 1) for w in w0)
bnds_2 = tuple((0, 0.00001) for w in w0)
opt = minimize(obj_func, w0, methods='SLSQP', bounds=(bnds_1, bnds_2))
```

I hope to let w lay in (0, 0.00001)U(0.025, 1), which means I allow it to be zero (approximately), but once it is larger than zero, the lower bound for it should be 0.025.

So how can I revise the bounds to meet the requirement? Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solvers in SciPy can't handle such a constraint.  They expect a feasible solution to satisfy all the constraints.  That is, the assumption is that you want to solve `bnds_1` *and* `bnds_2`.  There is no way to specify `bnds_1` *or* `bnds_2`.  (And to do so would require some sort of discrete optimization to be added to the solvers.)

You can solve the problem twice, once with just `bnds_1` and again with just `bnds_2`.  Then pick the best of the two solutions.